# Getting value from sqlite with index

Tags: c#, sqlite, radgridview, devart, dotconnect

**Edit:** I am using Devart LinqConnect Model. I think it is an entity framework. So I am getting datas with `LinqtoSQLiteDataContext _conn = new LinqtoSQLiteDataContext();` When I use `var persons = _conn.persons;`, it brings me all datas from `person` table. It pluralizes the table you know.

I am getting datas from sqlite file like this:

```
var persons = _conn.persons;
foreach (var person in persons)
{
   var r = radGridView1.Rows.AddNew();
   r.Cells[0].Value = person.Id;
   r.Cells[1].Value = person.Name;
   r.Cells[2].Value = person.Surname;
   r.Cells[3].Value = person.Age;
}
```

When I use bing methods, it brings me all columns but I don't want it. I want to show in the RadGridView some columns. So I create grid columns programmatically. But I think this method is so amateur. I want to iterate datas in one row with iteration number (index). I think it would be like this:

```
var persons = _conn.persons;
var i = 0;
foreach (var person in persons)
{
   var r = radGridView1.Rows.AddNew();
   r.Cells[i].Value = ?????;
   i++;
}
```

For this, I think it must be like: `r.Cells[i].Value = person.columns[i].Value;` But I don't know, what to write instead of question marks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write the marks either, but i have another way to do this.

What type of `persons` in your code?
I guess it's a `List<Person>`, if is true this code will be well.

```
//using System.ComponentModel;
var persons = _conn.persons;
radGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Person>(persons);
```

Or if it's a `DataTable`, using below code:

```
var persons = _conn.persons;
radGridView1.DataSource = persons;
```

If both of above are false, we can discuss continue how to solve it.

For amateur or expert just a matter of experience.

Comment: Firstl, thanks. I am using Devart LinqConnect Model. I think it is an entity framework. So I am getting datas with `LinqtoSQLiteDataContext _conn = new LinqtoSQLiteDataContext();` When I use `var persons = _conn.persons;`, it birngs me all datas from `person` table. It pluralize the table you know. It brings me all columns but I don't want it. I want to show in the RadGridView some columns. So I create grid columns programmatically. For this, I think it must be like: `r.Cells[i].Value = person.columns[i].Value;` But I don't konw how.

Comment: When your mouse move on persons in IDE, what does the tooltip show?

Comment: `Devart.Data.Linq.Table<person> persons`

Comment: Can you convert `persons ` to List<person> useing `ToList()` Method?

Comment: Yes I tried before. It  added to 1:1, 2:2 and 3:3 columns and rows `LinqtoSQLiteDataContext.persons` string.

Comment: I can't understand why `T` is `LinqtoSQLiteDataContext.persons`.Try useing .Select().ToList()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134863/discussion-between-johan-shen-and-habip-oguz).